# Why couldn’t Fiona stay as a human and Shrek an ogre?

Tags: shrek

Just, why not? She can be herself and him himself without any of them needing to change.

Besides, I think they might give birth to half-ogre humans or half-human ogres.

Comment: That's not how the magic works?

Comment: This question is likely to attract downvotes due to the unnecessary commentary.

Comment: Well. Have you see "the gif" involving black widow and the Hulk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The curse is explicit. While the curse operates, the cursee will oscillate between the two forms, human and ogre. When the curse is broken, the cursee will then **transform into the form (of the two) that their true love most desires.**

> *"By night one way
>
>   By day another.
>
>   This shall be the norm
>
>   Until you find true love's first kiss
>
>   And then take **love's true form"***

Obviously the curser expected her to revert to *human* form (by being rescued by a brave human) and most likely didn't expect that her true love would prefer her in her *ogre form*, but that's just how these things work out.

Comment: What about Dama Fortuna though?

Comment: @Adamant Well, some theorise SHE cursed Fiona, so there IS that.

Comment: Also, the magic-users In Shrek’s Swamp were seen at the wedding, so couldn’t one of THEM turn Fiona back into human. I know I would’ve.